# JQuery not working on less than IE v8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in JQuery coding and I encounter this problem, can someone explain to me why my **`JQuery`** code not working in IE version less than 8. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    $.post("getStatus.php",
    {
      WOID:$('#txtWOID').val(),

    },
    function(data,status){
      $(".meter > span").each(function() {
        $(this)
          .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
          .width(0)
          .animate({
            width: data
          }, 1200);
      });

      $("#display-result").html(data);

    });
  });
  });
```

And could you provide some recommended sites for jquery cross browser compatibility issue.

Any solutions or alternative is very much appreciated. Thanks.!

Comment: jQuery 2.x doesn't support IE8 and under.

Comment: IE7 is more than 10 years old. Time to give up on those users. or switch to jquery 1.12 and make everyone suffer... http://blog.jquery.com/2014/04/02/browser-support-in-jquery-1-12-and-beyond/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the browser support for jQuery: http://jquery.com/browser-support/

If you are using 2.X+, Only IE9+ is supported